# Clicking routes in Header refreshes page in vuejs with prerender-spa plugin after serving dist

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, prerender

The connection in between components gets disrupted. Which shouldnt happen since I am using bootstrap-vue inbuilt router link (using to=" " instead of href="").
The app works perfectly fine when running without dist.

---

App.vue

---

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <transition name="slide" mode="out-in">
          <router-view></router-view>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    appHeader: Header
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("initStocks");
  }
};
</script>
```

---

Header.vue

---

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="info">
      <b-navbar-brand to="/">Stock Broker</b-navbar-brand>

      <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

      <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
        <b-navbar-nav>
          <b-nav-item to="/portfolio">Portfolio</b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item to="/stocks">Stocks</b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item @click="endDay">End Day</b-nav-item>
          <b-navbar-nav right>
            <b-nav-item right>Funds: {{ funds }}</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-navbar-nav>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-navbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isDropdownOpen: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    funds() {
      return this.$store.getters.funds;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      randomizeStocks: "randomizeStocks",
      fetchData: "loadData"
    }),
    endDay() {
      this.randomizeStocks();
    },
    saveData() {
      const data = {
        funds: this.$store.getters.funds,
        stockPortfolio: this.$store.getters.stockPortfolio,
        stocks: this.$store.getters.stocks
      };
      this.$http.put("data.json", data);
    },
    loadData() {
      this.fetchData();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

---

vue.config.js

---

```js
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    prerenderSpa: {
      registry: undefined,
      renderRoutes: ["/", "/portfolio", "/stocks"],
      useRenderEvent: true,
      headless: true,
      onlyProduction: true
    }
  }
};
```

---

router/index.js

---

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/stocks',
    name: 'Stocks',
    component: () => import(/ '../views/Stocks.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/portfolio',
    name: 'Portfolio',
    component: () => import('../views/Portfolio.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it a minute after making this post haha.

The issue was that in App.vue I had my main div with a class of "container" instead of id of "app".

Corrected below:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app"> //correction here
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <transition name="slide" mode="out-in">
          <router-view></router-view>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```